# CSV files and MySQL triggers

Tags: php, mysql, csv, triggers

I'm trying to create a command line php script (user_upload.php) that accepts a csv file,
(users.csv) parses it and corrects the uppercase field in name, and surname before inserting into the mysql table called users.
I'm wanting to create a connection to the database, create a table, import and open a csv file, parse and correct the contents into capitalisation , before inserting into the table using a trigger
Then close the csv file, then close the connection.
I hope this makes sense.
It looks like it needs a massive tidy up, but not sure where to start.
your help would be great

cheers.

the (user_upload.php)file:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE users ( 
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
surname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50)
)";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table users created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}
$file = fopen("users.csv","r");
print_r(fgetcsv($file));
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER name_format 
    BEFORE INSERT ON users
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO users
    SET Name = CONCAT(UCASE(SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 1)),LCASE(SUBSTRING(Name, 2))),
    SET Surname = CONCAT(UCASE(SUBSTRING(Surname, 1, 1)),LCASE(SUBSTRING(Surname, 2))), 
        Name = OLD.Name,
        Surname = OLD.Surname;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
if (($handle = fopen("users.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $num = count($data);
                DB::table('users')->insert(
                    array('name' => $data[1], 'surname' => $data[2], 'email' => $data[3])
                );
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
fclose($file);
$conn->close();
?>
```

The (user.csv) file:

```
name    surname email
John    smith   jsmith@gmail.com
HaMish  JONES   ham@seek.com
Phil    CARRY   phil@open.edu.au
Johnny  O'Hare  john@yahoo.com.au
Mike    O'Connor    mo'connor@cat.net.nz
WILLIAM SMYthe  happy@ent.com.au
HAMISH  jones   ham@seek.com
Sam!!   WalTERS sam!@walters.org
Daley   thompson    daley@yahoo.co.nz
kevin   Ruley   kevin.ruley@gmail.com
Edward  JIKES   edward@jikes@com.au
```

Comment: but whats the question?

Comment: If you want to create a trigger in mysql you have to execute the code between the Delimiters as a query! This is no `PHP-Code`. Names can have multiple uppercase chars (e.g.: O'Hare) and not always the first char is an uppercase (e.g: van der Waals).